# Can ping subnet, but not the PC that is in subnet

Tags: networking, router

I have router and two computers that are connected to switch.

```
1st PC IP: 192.168.10.1/24  - gateway 192.168.10.3

2nd PC IP: 192.168.11.1/24 - gateway 192.168.11.3
```

They're connected to switch, that they could reach each other I connected router to switch as well.

Router belongs to both subnets, he has IP's:

```
eth1: 192.168.10.3/24
eth1: 192.168.11.3/24
```

from PC1 I can ping `192.168.11.3 (router)`, but can't ping the `PC2 192.168.11.1`. And vice versa.

Where's the problem?

I'm using mikrotik routers, PC are simulated by routers as well (I mean that I use router as PC)

Comment: Is the router configured to forward ICMP requests between networks?

Comment: Do both computers have 192.168.X.3 as default gateway ? OR if it is not the case, do both computers have the correct routes (192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.11.3 for PC1 and 192.168.11.0/24 via 192.168.10.3 for PC2) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you log into each MikroTik router (including the ones that are simulating the PCs), and execute `/ip export`, the '/ip address', '/ip firewall ...' and '/ip route' sections will likely show you where your problem is.

In general, a problem like this will come down to an improper IP configuration, a bad routing configuration or firewall rules.

Please forgive me for posting this as an answer... I do not have the score to comment, but I am very familiar with MikroTik routers, so wanted to get involved in this issue.

After looking at the output of the `/ip export`, if you're still having issues, please update your question with all three exports and I'll update my answer.

-Rich Alloway (RogueWave)